# Why I dont get response after successfully saving a serial number using ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am sending a post request from a scanner with scanned serial numbers to django server.
{"serial_number": "70:B3:D5:A9:C8:62", "bom": "2019/05/08"}

views.py

```
def camera_register(request):

    form = forms.RegisterCamerasForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instances = form.save(commit=False)
        # instances.serial_number = instances.serial_number.lower()
        instances.last_sighting_ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        instances.last_sighting_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        form.save()
        form.save_m2m()



        return JsonResponse(1, safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=200)
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterCamerasForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['group']
        model = camera_models.Camera
```

models.py

```
class Camera(TimeStampedModel):
    public_identifier = models.UUIDField(unique=True,
                                         default=uuid.uuid4,
                                         editable=False)

    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                     unique=True,
                                     null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    group = models.ForeignKey('CameraGroup',
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              null=True,
                              related_name='cameras',
                              related_query_name='cameras')
    # last seen at ip
    last_sighting_ip = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_sighting_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = CameraQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or self.serial_number or str(self.public_identifier)

    def as_json(self):
        return {
            'serial_number': self.serial_number
        }
```

I am sending the request and I save it to the database, but I do not get a response and I need that to be able to make a pytest and merge it to develop.
I tried saving it with form.save() form.save_m2m() since I am modifying some datata. I add time and IP adress.(Have to make it all lowercase but one thing a a time) 
When I am not saving it with form.save() I get a response, so this means my data is not valid in some way but I can't figure out how exactly.

I am sending the request via Restlet client , something similar to Postman and if I dont abourt the request it keeps going till infinity...

Comment: What error did you get ? What's traceback ?

Comment: Do you get a response when the form data is not valid?

Comment: I get response when I send the serial_number is already in the database {
"serial_number":[
"Camera with this Serial number already exists."
]
}  it comese from return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=200) in views.py , but when it is ok I do not get JsonResponse(1, safe=False) and everithing is signed in the dababase when I check.

Comment: when the serial number is not in the database I get this :/home/joro/.local/share/virtualenvs/serial_number-SMqsLoy9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Camera.last_sighting_time received a naive datetime (2019-05-23 19:59:41.701689) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
which comes from the current time I put in I think. When I already have that serial number in the DB I get:  [23/May/2019 20:01:44] "POST /api/3.0/camera_register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 69